How APEX's are mounted to loop devices
This page https://source.android.com/docs/core/ota/apex
apex_payload.img is an ext4 file system image backed by dm-verity. The image is mounted at runtime via a loopback device.
I have installed a debug image on my android device and have used adb root;adb shell to get root access on the android device. When I look at the mounts I see a lot of /dev/block/loop* entries:
/dev/block/loop20 on /apex/com.android.apex.cts.shim@1 type ext4 (ro,dirsync,seclabel,nodev,noatime)
/dev/block/loop21 on /apex/com.android.vndk.v34@1 type ext4 (ro,dirsync,seclabel,nodev,noatime)
If I look at
# cat /sys/devices/virtual/block/loop20/loop/backing_file
/system/apex/com.android.apex.cts.shim.apex

If I look that apex file seems to be a zip file as the document above mentions:
# file /system/apex/com.android.apex.cts.shim.apex
/system/apex/com.android.apex.cts.shim.apex: Zip archive data, requires at least v1.0 to extract
# unzip -l /system/apex/com.android.apex.cts.shim.apex
Archive:  /system/apex/com.android.apex.cts.shim.apex
  Length      Date    Time    Name
---------  ---------- -----   ----
      644  2009-01-01 00:00   META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
     1124  2009-01-01 00:00   AndroidManifest.xml
       40  2009-01-01 00:00   resources.arsc
     1032  2009-01-01 00:00   apex_pubkey
      779  2009-01-01 00:00   META-INF/CERT.SF
     1722  2009-01-01 00:00   META-INF/CERT.RSA
   274432  2009-01-01 00:00   apex_payload.img
    57875  2009-01-01 00:00   assets/NOTICE.html.gz
       29  2009-01-01 00:00   apex_manifest.pb
      884  2009-01-01 00:00   apex_build_info.pb
---------                     -------
   338561                     10 files

I can understand that the apex_payload.img file is an ext4 file image. But the loop20 backing store is the whole zip file ?
I guess I was expecting that the apex_payload.img file would be extracted from the apex zip file somewhere and then that image file would be the backing_file store for the loop20 device. But that doesn't seem to be the case.
Any insight on how the loop device can mount a zip file and be able to access the apex_payload.img file ?
Thanks
Chris

I have only ever used the loop device by doing a mount with the -o loop option. It seems that mount "does some stuff for you"
I have discovered the losetup command. I see that for a loop device you can set an offset and a size within the backing file to treat as an image. When I look at some of the devices with the losetup command I see that the loop devices has an offset and size defined:
# losetup -s /dev/block/loop17
/dev/block/loop17: [65025]:6047 (), offset 4096, sizelimit 114651136
# losetup -s /dev/block/loop20
/dev/block/loop20: [65025]:57 (), offset 4096, sizelimit 274432

So, it seems that the apex_payload.img file starts at the 4096 offset within the *.apex file. The bytes in the apex_paylod.img file are not compressed in anyway and are an array of bytes of the sizes shown above.
So, indeed the *.apex file is directly mounted by apexd which defines the offset and size of the apex_payload.img file within the *.apex zip file.
Thanks
Chris

That is the same technique used to load .so files directly from within an APK. By zipalign those uncompressed entries are aligned to 4096 byte boundaries so they can be directly mapped to memory.
